# How Can I get The Child Id Of the Root Node In Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my RealTime Database JSON data. I want to fetch the child id of the root node Assets. but can't seem to figure out as I am not using userid instead I am scanning a barcode and saving the data under the particular barcode number.

### Here's the Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those keys, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference assetsRef = rootRef.child("Assets");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
assetsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
CFM100010254BG
GE123100010254GB
```

If you want only the first child (`CFM100010254BG`), instead of using a `DatabaseReference`, please use the following query:

```
Query query = assetsRef.orderByChuild("asset_model").equalTo("CFM56");
```

And attach the listener on this query.

Comment: Note, that using this approach you will get/download all nodes in Assets with its full data, just for getting keys of child nodes. To optimize data flow you should create separate tree with keys only.